# VS Code insiders or VS Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Is everything from VS Code insiders, eventually going to be added to normal VS code? Is there a feature, where you can take features from insiders, and put it in normal VS code? I wanted to see if I should just go to VS code insiders for the extra features. Should I?

Answer (score 0):

I say that you shouldn't use insiders in a corporate environment as it still a kind of "beta" software, but if you're just having some fun, go for it. As for the features, most of them will eventually come to the stable release, but not all of them. I don't know of any way to "take" features from insider and put them on stable unless you want to go on GitHub and manually merge the branch and compile it.
Also, if you want to go for the features, I say you read the changelog of the insiders first.